# DateTimeParseException with LocalDateTime: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor

Tags: java, time

Here's my code:

```
private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd HH:mm:ss");

LocalDateTime timeStamp = LocalDateTime.parse(string, formatter);
```

Which results in the follwoing exception:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Oct 10 13:10:01' could
>   not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor:
>   {MonthOfYear=10, DayOfMonth=10},ISO resolved to 13:10:01 of type
>   java.time.format.Parsed

Using Java 1.8.0_31.

I did look around and found many similar issues but non of them matches this one exatcly and solutions offered there are not applicable here:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454025/unable-to-obtain-localdatetime-from-temporalaccessor-when-parsing-localdatetime) the reason for the same issue was using LocalDateTime without the Time parts. As you can see from the expection this is not the case here.

I'm not using week-based year as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603972/java8-localdatetime-parsing-error) example.

And finally unlike [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596530/unable-to-obtain-zoneddatetime-from-temporalaccessor-using-datetimeformatter-and) I'm using LocalDateTime so timezones should not be a problem. But as it's supposedly a [bug in DateTimeFormatter](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8041360) I've tried to pass the formatter as 'formatter.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())' (suggested workaround) which resulted in the same exception.

Comment: My guess is, that this is caused by the missing year in the value and the pattern.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this is indeed the case (nevermind my previous comment, I had used `YYYY` instead of `yyyy`) ; see [this ideone](https://ideone.com/4iS6Ty)

Comment: Yep thanks. @a_horse_with_no_name I will accept if you post this as an answer.

Comment: I have discussed the theory behind `java.time` at length here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56508200/145989

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A LocalDateTime needs a year - otherwise the formatter has no way to decide whether that 10th of October should be in 2016 or in 452 BC.

You can add a default behaviour to a `DateTimeFormatter`, for example with:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("MMM dd HH:mm:ss")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA, 2016)
        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Or make it a bit more flexible to default to the current year with:

```
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA, Year.now().getValue())
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980570/642706) is correct, and should be accepted.

## `MonthDay`

If you did indeed want a value of only a month and a day-of-month without any year, such as a recurring anniversary/birthday, then use the [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) class.

To parse a string into a `MonthDay`, call [`MonthDay.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) and pass a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) matching your String input format.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" )
                     .withLocale( Locale.ENGLISH );
MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse( "Oct 10 13:10:01" , f );
```

Similarly, you can represent the time-of-day with the [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class. Search Stack Overflow for countless examples.